# Is Lightsail the right solution to migrate the contents of a Mac OS Server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, migration, amazon-lightsail

Looking for a bit of help.

We have a physical Mac Server in the office, and wish to migrate away from this box into a cloud based solution.

The requirements are simple - we just need to be able to access the files on a frequent and reliable basis, through Finder or Win explorer. We don't want to have to use RDP.

At present, a Mac user can open finder, navigate to Shared > MacServer and pursue the various folders and their associated content.

If LightSail is the wrong solution here - what other arm of AWS would fit the bill?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not going to post an actual answer because I think your question is probably off-topic for this site. However it sounds like you just need a file storage service, not a server. Why not just use something like Dropbox, Box.com, Amazon Cloud Drive, Microsoft OneDrive, etc?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes have considered that - unsure what would be best to be honest. Perhaps Amazon Cloud Drive could be the best bet. Does it ultimately use S3?

Comment: Cloud Drive probably ultimately uses S3, but you would have no access or visibility into that. Is there a reason you are looking at AWS to solve this? You might look at AWS WorkDocs if you really want to use AWS.

Comment: I think the reason for our focus on AWS is that we use so much of the AWS suite, it feels it makes sense. The big driver behind this move is to come away from a physical box in the office, to something more reliable and robust. It could use any solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could store your data in Amazon S3 and use a product to 'mount' it on a Mac, such as:

- [Mountain Duck](https://mountainduck.io/)
- [ExpanDrive: Map & Mount SFTP, S3, OneDrive, Sharepoint, Dropbox, Google Drive, Box, WebDAV as Network Drive on Mac and Windows](https://www.expandrive.com/)
- [CloudMounter: Mount cloud drive as disk to Mac Finder and secure online storage](https://cloudmounter.net/)

Remember that S3 is not a drive, so these applications merely *synchronise* with S3. Problems could occur where files are updated simultaneously.

It could be simpler to use DropBox or Box.com.

Comment: thank you - this is exactly what we'll do using Expan Drive.